# Write both values and formulas at once in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

The row in my spreadsheet has format

```
<value>, <formula>, <value>, <formula>, ...
```

I need to update this row. Indeed, I can't use range.*setFormulas*, because it has values and I can't use range.*setValues*, because it has formulas. The only way I found - to set by one value, but this is very expensive if I have a lot of cols in my sheet.

Is there any way to set both formulas and values in one network request?

PS. To set value via *setFormula*('"' + str + '"') is not very good idea

Comment: Why is `setFormula('"' + str + '"')` not a very good idea? Do you want to edit formulas with your script? If not why not just put the values all next to each other and the formulas on the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't use range.setFormulas, because it has values and I can't use
>   range.setValues, because it has formulas

Wrong, just use setValues and if it is a formula add an equal sign to the beginning...

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue